# defineExpose stop unwrapping

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

i am currently try to expose an template ref with [`defineExpose`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose) for using that template ref in `useElementSize` composable. But as the documentation tells "(refs are automatically unwrapped just like on normal instances)". Because it will be unwrapped the parent component is not able to use `useElementSize`.

Sure the workaround could be to expose just the element size but i am curious if i can stop vue to unwrapp in `defineExpose`.

Answer (score 1):

If a ref is needed then it can be re-formed from unwrapped properties. For a read-only ref it would be:

```
const nestedRef = computed(() => someRef.value.nestedUnwrappedRef);
```